# how to add default value to the textbox helper through viewdata in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i want to add default value to the html text box by the view data. the foolwing code will give an idea wht i want to do exactly

, new { maxlength = 4 })%>

but it shows an error. plz tel me the solution for this.
thank in advance....

Answer (score 1):

You want to do this instead:

```
Html.TextBox("quantity", Html.Encode(ViewData["quantity"]), new { maxlength = 4 })
```

Note: I removed the scriptlet tags around your Html.Encode.
Once you're inside scriptlet tags, you don't need to use them again.